# Nada aperece en pantalla - pygame, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, game

Estoy intentando hacer un juego en 2d, con un mundo generado a partir de una imágen en pixeles de diferentes colores. Alternativamente, será terreno normal, agua o los límites, lo prohibido. Dado que necesito que sea un mundo muy ámplio, debo distribuirlo en chunks y hacer que estos se carguen y descarguen al estar a cierta distancia de el chunk en el que está el jugador con su avatar. De momento el avatar es un quadrado, dado que solo estoy probando la generación de mundo y la carga-descarga de chunks. En teoria no hay nada de malo, sin embargo no funciona. La pantalla simplemente se queda negra.

Alguna idea? Por favor, llevo días con esto.

```
from PIL import Image
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 750))

all_chunks = pygame.sprite.Group()
visible_chunks = pygame.sprite.Group()
players = pygame.sprite.Group()
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pos_x = 0
        self.pos_y = 0

        self.m_r = False
        self.m_l = False
        self.m_u = False
        self.m_d = False

        self.speed = 3

        self.scrolling_x = 0
        self.scrolling_y = 0

        self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
        self.image.fill((255,100,255))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.pos_x, self.pos_y, 10, 10)

    def update(self):
        if self.m_r == True:
            self.scrolling_x = self.speed
        if self.m_l == True:
            self.scrolling_x = (0 - self.speed) 
        if self.m_u == True:
            self.scrolling_y = self.speed
        if self.m_d == True:
            self.scrolling_y = (0 - self.speed)

        if self.m_r == False:
            self.scrolling_x = 0
        if self.m_l == False:
            self.scrolling_x = 0
        if self.m_u == False:
            self.scrolling_y = 0
        if self.m_d == True:
            self.scrolling_y = 0


player = Player()
players.add(player)







class Controller():
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = []
        self.image_map_file = "image_map_file.png"
        self.t_file = None
        self.t_file = None
        self.image_size = None
        self.current_color = None
        self.opened_image = Image.open(self.image_map_file)
        self.loaded = self.opened_image.load()
        self.image_size = self.opened_image.size


        self.width = 30
        self.height = 30

        self.chunk_place_x = 0
        self.chunk_place_y = 0

        self.t_file = None
        self.current_pixel = 0



    def create_t(self):
        for i in range(self.image_size[0]):
            self.t.append(["-"]*self.image_size[1])
control = Controller()
control.create_t()
class chunk(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, biome, pos_x, pos_y, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.biome = biome
        self.pos_x = pos_x
        self.pos_y = pos_y
        self.is_loaded = False

    @classmethod  
    def calificate(cls):
        for y in range(control.image_size[1]):
            for x in range(control.image_size[0]):
                control.current_pixel = control.loaded[x,y]  # Get the RGBA Value of the a pixel of an image
                if control.current_pixel[0] == 255: #Si és vemrell....
                    control.t[x][y] = 0
                elif control.current_pixel[1] == 255:
                    control.t[x][y] = 1
                elif control.current_pixel[2] == 255:
                    control.t[x][y] = 2
                x += 1
            y +=1

    def load(self):
        if self.biome == "nice_desert":
            self.image = pygame.Surface((control.width, control.height))
            self.image.fill((255,184,77))
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.pos_x, self.pos_y, control.width, control.height)
        if self.biome == "water":
            self.image = pygame.Surface((control.width, control.height))
            self.image.fill((0,0,255))
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.pos_x, self.pos_y, control.width, control.height)
        if self.biome == "forbidden":
            self.image = pygame.Surface((control.width, control.height))
            self.image.fill((255,0,0))
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.pos_x, self.pos_y, control.width, control.height)
        visible_chunks.add(self)
        self.is_loaded = True

    def unload(self):
        self.is_loaded = False
        try:
            del self.image
        except:
            pass
        try:            
            del self.rect
        except:
            pass
    
    def find_itself(self):
        self.comprehension = []
        self.result = [0,0]
        for i in range(control.image_size[0]):
            self.comprehension = control.t[i]
            try:
                self.result[1] = self.comprehension.index(self)
                self.result[0] = i
                return self.result
            except ValueError:
                pass
            


    def update(self, scrolling_x, scrolling_y):
        try:
            if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, players):
                now = self.find_itself()
                for i in range(10):
                    control.t[now[0]-5+i][now[1]+5].load
                    control.t[now[0]+5][now[1]+5-i].load
                    control.t[now[0]+5-i][now[1]-5].load
                    control.t[now[0]-5][now[1]-5+i].load 
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        
        self.pos_x += scrolling_x
        self.pos_y += scrolling_y

        if self.is_loaded == True:
            self.rect.x = self.pos_x
            self.rect.y = self.pos_y
    
                     #Linia 100,, UUUUUUUU
                   #Això ho ha escrit el Hansel! :D
                   #ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ

def paint():
    for y in range(control.image_size[1]):
        for x in range(control.image_size[0]):
            if control.t[x][y] == 0:
                control.t[x][y] = chunk("forbidden", control.chunk_place_x, control.chunk_place_y, all_chunks)
            if control.t[x][y] == 1:
                control.t[x][y] = chunk("nice_desert", control.chunk_place_x, control.chunk_place_y, all_chunks)
            if control.t[x][y] == 2:
                control.t[x][y] = chunk("water", control.chunk_place_x, control.chunk_place_y, all_chunks)
            control.chunk_place_x += control.width
        control.chunk_place_x = 0
        control.chunk_place_y += control.height

chunk.calificate()
paint()
print(control.t[0][0])
control.t[0][0].load()


def main():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    player.m_r = True
                
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    player.m_l = True
                
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    player.m_u = True
                
                if event.key == K_DOWN:
                    player.m_d = True
                


            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    player.m_r = False
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    player.m_l = False

                if event.key == K_UP:
                    player.m_u = False

                if event.key == K_DOWN:
                    player.m_d = False 

        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        #print(len(sprites.sprites))
        players.draw(screen)
        players.update()
        visible_chunks.draw(screen)
        all_chunks.update(player.scrolling_x, player.scrolling_y)
        pygame.display.flip()


main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

En tu main hace falta `pygame.display.update()` (O `pygame.display.flip()`) para que sea posible mostrar los cambios en el display, por eso se ve todo negro

Si lo agregas a la función del main ya se ve un cuadro rojo (Que no sé si es lo que quieres que se vea porque no tengo tu imagen que genera el mapa)

```
def main():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    player.m_r = True
                
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    player.m_l = True
                
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    player.m_u = True
                
                if event.key == K_DOWN:
                    player.m_d = True
                


            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    player.m_r = False
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    player.m_l = False

                if event.key == K_UP:
                    player.m_u = False

                if event.key == K_DOWN:
                    player.m_d = False 

        
        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        #print(len(sprites.sprites))
        players.draw(screen)
        players.update()
        visible_chunks.draw(screen)
        all_chunks.update(player.scrolling_x, player.scrolling_y)
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Maravilloso, mil gracias! Me había dado cuenta poco después de hacer la pregunta, pero en lugar de pygame.display.update() he puesto pygame.display.flip, que por algun motivo no funciona igual. Mil gracias!